# Sequence coverage - puzzles to solve

Tags: r

I would like to create a script which can be used to check and highlight sequence coverage.

That is a sequence:

```
> dput(dat1)
c("M", "A", "N", "Y", "K", "K", "P", "K", "L", "L", "Y", "C", 
"S", "N", "G", "G", "H", "F", "L", "R", "I", "L", "P", "D", "G", 
"T", "V", "D", "G", "T", "R", "D", "R", "S", "D", "Q", "H", "I", 
"Q", "L", "Q", "L", "S", "A", "E", "S", "V", "G", "E", "V", "Y", 
"I", "K", "S", "T", "E", "T", "G", "Q", "Y", "L", "A", "M", "D", 
"T", "D", "G", "L", "L", "Y", "G", "S", "Q", "T", "P", "N", "E", 
"E", "C", "L", "F", "L", "E", "R", "L", "E", "E", "N", "H", "Y", 
"N", "T", "Y", "I", "S", "K", "K", "H", "A", "E", "K", "N", "W", 
"F", "V", "G", "L", "K", "K", "N", "G", "S", "C", "K", "R", "G", 
"P", "R", "T", "H", "Y", "G", "Q", "K", "A", "I", "L", "F", "L", 
"P", "L", "P", "V", "S", "S", "D", "G", "G", "G", "G", "S", "G", 
"G", "G", "G", "S", "G", "G", "G", "G", "S", "A", "N", "Y", "K", 
"K", "P", "K", "L", "L", "Y", "C", "S", "N", "G", "G", "H", "F", 
"L", "R", "I", "L", "P", "D", "G", "T", "V", "D", "G", "T", "R", 
"D", "R", "S", "D", "Q", "H", "I", "Q", "L", "Q", "L", "S", "A", 
"E", "S", "V", "G", "E", "V", "Y", "I", "K", "S", "T", "E", "T", 
"G", "Q", "Y", "L", "A", "M", "D", "T", "D", "G", "L", "L", "Y", 
"G", "S", "Q", "T", "P", "N", "E", "E", "C", "L", "F", "L", "E", 
"R", "L", "E", "E", "N", "H", "Y", "N", "T", "Y", "I", "S", "K", 
"K", "H", "A", "E", "K", "N", "W", "F", "V", "G", "L", "K", "K", 
"N", "G", "S", "C", "K", "R", "G", "P", "R", "T", "H", "Y", "G", 
"Q", "K", "A", "I", "L", "F", "L", "P", "L", "P", "V", "S", "S", 
"D")
```

And below I put "puzzles". I would like to check what percentage of sequence is covered and highlight possible missing spots:

```
 >dput(evidence1)
c("AILFLPLPVSSD", "AILFLPLPVSSDGGGGSGGGGSGGGGSANYK", "AILFLPLPVSSDGGGGSGGGGSGGGGSANYKKPK", 
"AILFLPLPVSSDGGGGSGGGGSGGGGSANYKKPKLLYCSNGGHFLR", "ANYKKPK", 
"ANYKKPKLLYCSNGGHFLR", "CLFLER", "CLFLERLE", "DRSDQHIQLQLSAE", 
"DRSDQHIQLQLSAESVGE", "ENHYNTYISKK", "GPRTHYGQK", "GPRTHYGQKAILFLPLPVSSD", 
"HAEKNWFVGLK", "ILPDGTVDGTR", "ILPDGTVDGTRDR", "ILPDGTVDGTRDRSDQHIQLQLSAE", 
"KNWFVGLK", "KNWFVGLKK", "LEENHYNTYISK", "LLYCSNGGHFLR", "LLYCSNGGHFLRILPDGTVDGTR", 
"LLYCSNGGHFLRILPDGTVDGTRDR", "MANYKKPKLLYCSNGGHFLR", "NGSCKRGPR", 
"NHYNTYISK", "NHYNTYISKK", "NHYNTYISKKHAE", "NWFVGLK", "NWFVGLKK", 
"RGPRTHYGQK", "SDQHIQLQLSAE", "SDQHIQLQLSAESVGE", "SDQHIQLQLSAESVGEVYIK", 
"STETGQYLAMDTDGLLYGSQTPNEE", "SVGEVYIKSTE", "TGQYLAMDTDGLLYGSQTPNEE", 
"THYGQK", "THYGQKAILFLPLPVSSD", "THYGQKAILFLPLPVSSDGGGGSGGGGSGGGGSANYK", 
"THYGQKAILFLPLPVSSDGGGGSGGGGSGGGGSANYKKPK", "VYIKSTE")
```

As an example of visual presentation of missing parts of sequence can be seen below but any other clear method showing what parts are missing is more than welcome.

[image: Example]

Is it doable ?

Comment: Could you add a desired output coherent to your data (if the image is coherent, I'm missing something...)?

Comment: Image is not coherent. Unfortunately, I am unable to provide you desired output coherent to my data because I am unable to create it. I can only tell you that sequence coverage should be 100% for this particular example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This won't be the prettiest code, but you could accomplish what you want to do using the `tidyverse` package.

```
library(tidyverse)
sequence <- c("M", "A", "N", "Y", "K", "K", "P", "K", "L", "L", "Y", "C", 
  "S", "N", "G", "G", "H", "F", "L", "R", "I", "L", "P", "D", "G", 
  "T", "V", "D", "G", "T", "R", "D", "R", "S", "D", "Q", "H", "I", 
  "Q", "L", "Q", "L", "S", "A", "E", "S", "V", "G", "E", "V", "Y", 
  "I", "K", "S", "T", "E", "T", "G", "Q", "Y", "L", "A", "M", "D", 
  "T", "D", "G", "L", "L", "Y", "G", "S", "Q", "T", "P", "N", "E", 
  "E", "C", "L", "F", "L", "E", "R", "L", "E", "E", "N", "H", "Y", 
  "N", "T", "Y", "I", "S", "K", "K", "H", "A", "E", "K", "N", "W", 
  "F", "V", "G", "L", "K", "K", "N", "G", "S", "C", "K", "R", "G", 
  "P", "R", "T", "H", "Y", "G", "Q", "K", "A", "I", "L", "F", "L", 
  "P", "L", "P", "V", "S", "S", "D", "G", "G", "G", "G", "S", "G", 
  "G", "G", "G", "S", "G", "G", "G", "G", "S", "A", "N", "Y", "K", 
  "K", "P", "K", "L", "L", "Y", "C", "S", "N", "G", "G", "H", "F", 
  "L", "R", "I", "L", "P", "D", "G", "T", "V", "D", "G", "T", "R", 
  "D", "R", "S", "D", "Q", "H", "I", "Q", "L", "Q", "L", "S", "A", 
  "E", "S", "V", "G", "E", "V", "Y", "I", "K", "S", "T", "E", "T", 
  "G", "Q", "Y", "L", "A", "M", "D", "T", "D", "G", "L", "L", "Y", 
  "G", "S", "Q", "T", "P", "N", "E", "E", "C", "L", "F", "L", "E", 
  "R", "L", "E", "E", "N", "H", "Y", "N", "T", "Y", "I", "S", "K", 
  "K", "H", "A", "E", "K", "N", "W", "F", "V", "G", "L", "K", "K", 
  "N", "G", "S", "C", "K", "R", "G", "P", "R", "T", "H", "Y", "G", 
  "Q", "K", "A", "I", "L", "F", "L", "P", "L", "P", "V", "S", "S", 
  "D")
df <- tibble(
  evidence = c(
    "AILFLPLPVSSD",
    "AILFLPLPVSSDGGGGSGGGGSGGGGSANYK", 
    "AILFLPLPVSSDGGGGSGGGGSGGGGSANYKKPK", 
    "AILFLPLPVSSDGGGGSGGGGSGGGGSANYKKPKLLYCSNGGHFLR",
    "ANYKKPK", 
    "ANYKKPKLLYCSNGGHFLR", 
    "CLFLER", 
    "CLFLERLE", 
    "DRSDQHIQLQLSAE", 
    "RSDQHIQLQLSAESVGE", 
    "ENHYNTYISKK", 
    "GPRTHYGQK", 
    "GPRTHYGQKAILFLPLPVSSD", 
    "HAEKNWFVGLK",
    "ILPDGTVDGTR", 
    "ILPDGTVDGTRDR", 
    "ILPDGTVDGTRDRSDQHIQLQLSAE", 
    "KNWFVGLK", 
    "KNWFVGLKK", 
    "LEENHYNTYISK", 
    "LLYCSNGGHFLR", 
    "LLYCSNGGHFLRILPDGTVDGTR", 
    "LLYCSNGGHFLRILPDGTVDGTRDR", 
    "MANYKKPKLLYCSNGGHFLR", 
    "NGSCKRGPR", 
    "NHYNTYISK", 
    "NHYNTYISKK", 
    "NHYNTYISKKHAE", 
    "NWFVGLK", 
    "NWFVGLKK", 
    "RGPRTHYGQK", 
    "SDQHIQLQLSAE", 
    "SDQHIQLQLSAESVGE", 
    "SDQHIQLQLSAESVGEVYIK", 
    "STETGQYLAMDTDGLLYGSQTPNEE",
    "SVGEVYIKSTE", 
    "TGQYLAMDTDGLLYGSQTPNEE", 
    "THYGQK", 
    "THYGQKAILFLPLPVSSD", 
    "THYGQKAILFLPLPVSSDGGGGSGGGGSGGGGSANYK", 
    "THYGQKAILFLPLPVSSDGGGGSGGGGSGGGGSANYKKPK", 
    "VYIKSTE")
)
df <- mutate(
  df,
  length = nchar(evidence),
  index = lapply(sapply(evidence, gregexpr, text = str_c(sequence, collapse = '')), as.numeric),
  coverage = map2(
    length, index,
    function (len, idx) {
      as.vector(
        sapply(
          unlist(idx), 
          function (x, y) {
            return (x + y)
          }, 
          y = seq(len) - 1
        )
      )
    }
  )
)
sequence[unique(unlist(df$coverage))] <- '✔'
print(str_c(sequence, collapse = ''))
```

I set up a `tbl_df` (`tibble data.frame`) to store the patterns (`evidence`), then added three columns called `length`, `index`, and `coverage`. The `length` column stores the number of characters in each pattern and  the `index` column stores the starting indices, if any, of exact matches in the sequence. The third column, `coverage`, is defined by calculating all index positions in `sequence` that has been covered by one of the `evidence` patterns.

```
# A tibble: 6 x 4
  evidence                                       length index        coverage  
  <chr>                                           <int> <named list> <list>    
1 AILFLPLPVSSD                                       12 <dbl [2]>    <dbl [24]>
2 AILFLPLPVSSDGGGGSGGGGSGGGGSANYK                    31 <dbl [1]>    <dbl [31]>
3 AILFLPLPVSSDGGGGSGGGGSGGGGSANYKKPK                 34 <dbl [1]>    <dbl [34]>
4 AILFLPLPVSSDGGGGSGGGGSGGGGSANYKKPKLLYCSNGGHFLR     46 <dbl [1]>    <dbl [46]>
5 ANYKKPK                                             7 <dbl [2]>    <dbl [14]>
6 ANYKKPKLLYCSNGGHFLR                                19 <dbl [2]>    <dbl [38]>
```

Finally, `unique` is called on the `unlist`ed `coverage` column to get all index positions that have been accounted for, and those index positions in `sequence` are replaced with fancy check marks (✔).

For the specific example you've provided, the output is all check marks since all letters in the sequence were accounted for:

```
[1] "✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔✔"
```

In scenarios where not all characters are accounted for, you will encounter something like `"...✔✔LEF✔✔✔✔TOVER✔✔✔✔✔✔CH✔ARA✔✔CTER✔S..."`.